# OpenCV2.4.3 Program Can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing

Tags: opencv

Since last month I was working with OpenCV2.2(pre-built) using c functions only in code::blocks. But I need to shift to c++ API. But when I run the c++ code I am getting error like "undefined reference to c++ function". I just search in internet and found that I need to build from source. So I just moved to OpenCV2.4.3. These are my setting what I do with OpenCV2.4.3 for configuring project in code::blocks.

1. Extract OpenCV2.4.3 to E:\opencv
2. Add the line "E:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin" to path.
3. And in code::blocks set up the project like
   -> Compiler and debugger setting->search directories add "E:\opencv\build\include"
   -> In linker tab add "E:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin"
   -> In limker setting tab add "E:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib"

And I build my project successfully but while I am running my project I am getting the error like "Program Can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing from your computer".
I am using code::blocks with MingGW compiler.

My questions are
1. Why I can't run c++ code using OpenCV2.2 while c code is successfully build and ran. Is it the pre-built library problem. If so where can I download OpenCV pre-built library which support both c and c++ code.
2. Why the MingGW compiler showing the  error like "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing "for  OpenCV2.4.3 where as OpenCV2.2 successfully build and ran using the same MingGW compiler.

Any help will appreciated.

Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I switched from OpenCV 2.0 to OpenCV 2.4.3. So I will suggest the following.

1. Uninstall both CodeBlocks and Opencv 2.4.3
2. Reinstall both and integrate them using the same steps you followed earlier.

Let us know if this works.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I have reinstall both but still the problem. Are you using code::blocks with Mingw compiler suit or separate mingw compiler.

Comment: I am using code::blocks with Mingw compiler suite. Try searching for similar posts on CodeBlocks website. Last resort may be switching to Visual Studio.